# how to iterate category options with edit blade file in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

working with laravel 6 and need edit category options here.
PostController.php

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        $cats = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cats[$category->id] = $category->name;
        }
        return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats);
    }
```

and edit.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Category</label>

    <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
      @foreach($categories as $cats)
      <option value="{{$post->category->id}}">{{$post->category->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
      </select>
</div>
```

but when I am going to edit page in the edit category options display only current category item. I need display all categories in the table? how could I manage this?

Comment: I'm confused of what you're trying to achieve ... In controller you are passing $cats, then in view you iterate $categories as $cats but for option you use $post->category->id which always will be the same thing ... Are you trying to change post category ?

Comment: maybe you want something like 
@foreach($categories as $key => $name)
<option value="{{$key}}">{{$name}}</option> ...

Comment: yes I need your second comment

Comment: it is not working yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply like this :

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('posts.edit', compact(['post', 'categories']));
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Category</label>

   <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id">
      @foreach($categories as $cat)
           <option value="{{$cat->id}}" @if($cat->id === $post->category_id) 'selected' @endif >{{$cat->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `$cat->id === $post->category_id` in the @if on option tag

Comment: @Donkarnash, yes thanks for pointing it out